# how to use third party script with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have got third polling scripts which has it's own admin panel, i want to integrate with my existing codeigniter site, what is the best way to iplement it ?

Comment: Do you want it to fit your url scheme? Or run on every page load or what? We'll need more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the polling script into `application/libraries` and then initialize it using `$this->load->library('yourclass');` [Here is the documentation from the user guide.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the files of the 3rd party script into a folder `application/third_party`
2. Refer to the script using require_once APPPATH . `'/third_party/script_folder/script.main.class.php';`